# Android AndEngine: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig found

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm doing a REALLY simple app, a basic hello world to test AndEngine and I am currently having some problems when running it:
I set my emulator properties as RealMayo suggests in his videos and it should work but I get this error instead

```
07-23 13:10:23.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1485): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No        EGLConfig found!
```

Anyone has encountered the same situation, or may know how to solve it?

I am almost tempted to not us AndEngine at all... as a simple app has been really difficult to run.

NOTE: I have found some posts but they are at least 3 months old and the use of emulators has been fixed not long ago.

Anyways Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure your AVD is at least Android version 4.0.3

see this thread http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/api-level-t8230.html

Comment: Select AVD version is 4.0.3 and check Use Host GPU , its woking for me on 4.0.3 emulator. Please go through below site it will help you to set in GPU Host on old AVD and updated AVD.

Comment: Thanks ! I was missing "Use Host GPU" ...works fine on API 18 (4.3) emulator

Answer (score 0):

just to add a small addition to the answer above (answer #1): make sure along creating an AVD with **API level 15** (Android 4.0.3), that imported **AndEngine** library's project target is also built with Android 4.0.3. To validate: right click on **AndEngine** library in eclipse project, choose "**properties**", in the left pane of opened window click on "**Android**" label; in right pane verify that "Android 4.0.3" checkbox is checked. If "Android 4.0.3" option is not listed there, just import it with Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Ravikumar11 about GPU helped me get this resolved.

Additionally, I had to:

1. Update the SDK with all options for my current API (17) and the general tools (binary downloads that are not API-specific)
2. As eclipse suggests after SDK update, run Check for Updates in eclipse and a bunch of stuff gets loaded subsequently

From there, I was able to run my AndEngine app in the emulator